# How can i deal with the last jump?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A bunny can hop at most 50 centimetres far. It wants to cross to the other side of the river, but it cannot swim. So the only hope is to hop on the rocks on the river, which are positioned in a straight line. The positions of the rocks are measured from the start location, assuming that the bunny starts at the 0 cm mark. The opposite bank could be treated as a big rock. It is the final rock in the tuple of rocks.

For example, the rocks are at locations 32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, and the opposite riverbank at location 145.
For the above example, it needs to make 3 jumps, at rock 0 (starting point), rock 46, and rock 96 to reach the other side (rock 146).

The bunny will jump as far as it could for each hop. What is the smallest number of jumps it needs to take to reach the other side of the river?

You may assume that there are at most 20 rocks (including the opposite bank).

Write a function rabbit that reads in a tuple that represents the locations of the rocks. Your function should return the minimum number of jumps needed, or -1 if it is not possible for the bunny to reach the other side of the river. You may assume that the locations of the rocks in the tuple are valid (bigger than 0) and they are sorted in ascending order.

```
def rabbit(rocks):
    jumps = 0
    prev = 0
    cursor = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(rocks):
        rock = rocks[i]
        if rock - prev < 50:
            cursor = rock
            i += 1
            continue
        elif rock - prev >= 50 and prev != cursor:
            jumps += 1
            prev = cursor
            continue
        else:
            return -1

    if i == len(rocks):
        rock = rocks[i-1]
        if rock - prev <= 50:
            jumps += 1

    if jumps == 0:
        return -1
    return jumps
```

Some cases here:

rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145)) should generate a 3. But i got 4 instead.

rabbit((30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258)) and for this case. There is the problem with the last jump. Although i got the answer of 7, the last part of the code seem to contradict with the first case.

Comment: Your code looks fine and try to modify the code to check one step ahead before counting the steps.

Comment: That's where i get a little lost. I cant seem to figure out how to check one step ahead

Comment: What should be the answer for `rabbit((30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258))`, also can you outline how you will get answer `3` for `rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145)) `

Comment: Why is the answer for the second one 15? Shouldn't it be 7?

Comment: Your if conditions were slightly off, I provided the correct conditions in my answer below @ShehanDhaleesha, please have a look

Comment: @gmds sorry for the confusion, it should be 7. Made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed part of the code as below.

```
if rock - prev <= 50:
    cursor = rock
    i += 1
    continue
elif rock - prev > 50 and prev != cursor:
    jumps += 1
    prev = cursor
    continue
```

Since the rabbit can jump atmost 50, that means it can jump 50, so that needs to be `rock - prev <= 50`, and it cannot jump more than 50, which is covered by `rock - prev > 50 and prev != cursor`

After this I get the output as below:

```
print(rabbit((32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145)))
#3
print(rabbit((30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258)))
#7
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you @tanteidaiko :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution using recursion:

```
def rabbit(rocks, jumps=0):
    max_jump = max(element for element in rocks if element <= 50)
    last = rocks[-1]
    if max_jump >= last:
        return jumps + 1

    else:
        return rabbit([rock - max_jump for rock in rocks if rock > 50], jumps + 1)

print(rabbit([32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145]))
print(rabbit([30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258]))
```

Output:

```
3
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
MAX_JUMP_DIS = 50


def rabbit(rocks):
    ans_rock = []

    def jump(rocks, cur_pos=0):
        list_possible = [rock for rock in rocks if rock <= MAX_JUMP_DIS + cur_pos]
        if len(list_possible) == 0:
            return -1
        jump_pos = max(list_possible)
        ans_rock.append(jump_pos)
        [rocks.remove(rock) for rock in list_possible]
        if len(rocks) != 0:
            return jump(rocks, cur_pos=jump_pos)

    if jump(rocks) == -1:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(f"rock list: {ans_rock} count:{len(ans_rock)}")


rabbit([32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 7000])
rabbit([32, 46, 70, 85, 96, 123, 145])
rabbit([30, 70, 75, 120, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 246, 258])
```

**output:**

```
-1
rock list: [46, 96, 145] count:3
rock list: [30, 75, 120, 170, 200, 246, 258] count:7
```